# Filtering the divs with data attributes with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am having a div structures with multiple data attributes like data-location,data-name.
I want to filter the displayed divs on basis of location and name checkboxes defined in my code.
Like if i check some location from location checkboxes,it should show only those location divs.and same for name checkboxes
But when i select name and location both,then it should compare the both and show me the divs combining the both.

```
<div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-location="US">Peter</div><br />
<div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-location="Mexico">Willy</div><br />
<div class="content" data-name="Roche" data-location="US">Roche</div><br />
<div class="content" data-name="George" data-location="Canada">George</div><br />
<div class="content" data-name="Pedro" data-location="Mexico">Pedro</div><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="name" id="Peter">Peter
<input type="checkbox" name="name" id="Willy">Peter
<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="US">US
<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="Mexico">US
```

So if i select Peter checkbox only,it should show all peter resulted divs.and if i select US location div only,it should give only US related divs with all names
if i select Peter and US checkbox,then it should give Only Peter with location US resulted divs.

Comment: Do you have some html / javascript code for us to look at?

Comment: @Jorg-i have posted the html.Please help...

Comment: do i need to paste sumthing more to analyze?

Comment: Check out the following plugin: [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) It allows you to filter between divs

Comment: There are enough answers for you to build on to get what you want. So, give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [Updated Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unknownuser/A4v2E/1/)
jquery

```
$('div>').change(function() {
$(".content").hide();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {          
       $(".content[data-name="+this.id+"]").show();
       $(".content[data-location="+this.id+"]").show();    
    }

});
```

and in CSS you need to set display to make all content hide

```
.content{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir.its showing incorrect result.When u r checking two checkboxes like one for name and one for location.You need to see in which div is having name as peter and location as US.But according to u,ur code is showing all the two divs on checking name=peter and loca-US.Ideally it should show one.because only first div is having nam-peter and location-US

Comment: Thanks a lot.exactly what i was looking for.Just a small correction in this one.when u are checking peter,shows divs with names as peter,at the same time if u check willy also(means peter and willy both are selected)then it should show both peter and willy divs i.e. all the four divs.Currently when u r checking willy with peter,its hiding peter divs wheras it should keep peter divs displayed.

Comment: Secondly,when u check willy and mexico,it shows exact matching results.At that time willy and mexico checkboxes are on.at that time if u check US checkbox also then it should show two divs i.e.willy with mexico and willy with US.but currently when u check US with mexico for willy,its showing divs for second checkbox that you checked i.e.US only after checking mexico.But thanks a lot for the time shared for the requirement.

Comment: @user3321823-can u please make a small change in above code given by you for the scenario i told u above comment starting from thanks a lot..Thanks for your timely help..

Comment: ok i will and yah do not thanx me in comment instead you can accept my answer by accepting my answer(click on 'right sign' on left of my answer.. :)

Comment: ya sure but you just have to wait little:)

Comment: please update sir for the updated coded fiddle @user3321823.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have any other choice but to iterate through all the *checked* `checkbox` every time there is a `change` event and hide/show the `div`s accordingly so I would do :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
        if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0) {
            // no one is checked so show all
            $(".content").show();
        } else {
            // there is at least one checked
            $(".content").fadeOut(0); // hide all (again)
            // show only each of those that match
            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                $(".content[data-name=" + this.id + "]").fadeIn(100);
                $(".content[data-location=" + this.id + "]").fadeIn(100);
            }); // each
        };
    }); // on
}); // ready
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq7vN/)</kbd>

**NOTES** :

- you could use a *class* instead of the `input[type=checkbox]` element
- `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

Comment: can u plz help me with code snippet for iteration through all checkboxes as the above code given by you is not what i want.

Comment: so please help me in that sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
$(".content").hide();
$(".content[data-name="+this.id+"]").show();
$(".content[data-location="+this.id+"]").show();

});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8aD59/2/)

**Edit**

```
 $(".content").hide();
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {

 if (this.checked) {
     $(".content[data-name=" + this.id + "]").show();
     $(".content[data-location=" + this.id + "]").show();
 } else {
     $(".content[data-name=" + this.id + "]").hide();
     $(".content[data-location=" + this.id + "]").hide();
 }
 });
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8aD59/6/)

Comment: thanks fr your help.but there are a or 2 things wrong,rest is fine.When you are checking Peter checkbox and Mexico checkbox,it should only show div with data name as peter and data-location as Mexico.But when i run your code,its showing both things Mexico locations also with other data-names

Comment: Sorry,but still the same.when your have checked the checkbox for first time like peter checkbox.and then you got divs with peter names,after that you are checking location div like US,then u have to compare the two checkboxes values and show the divs.like Peter as name and US as location.no other name should come.Like Only first div should be visible.But with your code when u check peter first and US next,its showing Roche also,whereas we should get div only with name peter.